# Example when the identity operator isn't an isometry

Tags: complex-analysis

Example when the identity function isn't an isometry?

I'm thinking about this but i can't find an example of that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** The identity function $Id: (X, d_1) \to (X,d_2)$ is an isometry is implies that the two metrics are equivalent.

Use any two metrics which are not equivalent.

Comment: That’s not true, is it? An isometry is distance-preserving, but equivalent metrics needn’t be. For example, $d$ and $2d$ are equivalent (generate the same open sets), but clearly $(X,d)\to(X,2d)$, with $x\mapsto x$, is not distance-preserving. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: But you are right in saying that two inequivalent metrics will produce an example where the identity is not an isometry, so +1 for that.

Comment: @MPW You are right, I said isometry but was think homeomorphic